# When I click on af:commandLink page is blinking

Tags: oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I am develong  a web application using Oracle ADF(12c). I have a page with two links that looks like below

[image: Page with 2 links]

Everything is working fine. when I click on any link it is going to desired page but before going to the desired page it is blinking. Means it is not behaving normally. Means when I click on any link it has to go the desired page without blinking.

Help me . I achieving this.

Answer (score 0):

This means there is something wrong with your custom skin - if you have one. Maybe you can try to spot that color somewhere in your skin CSS.

Alternatively, you can try playing with these selectors, changing the background colour to be the same as menu's background:

.AFLinkForeground
.AFLinkHover
.AFVisitedLinkBackground
.AFActiveLinkBorder
.AFActiveLinkForeground
.AFLinkForeground
.AFVisitedLinkForeground
.AFLinkForeground
.AFLightVisitedLinkForeground
.AFLinkForeground
.AFDisabledLinkForeground
.AFLinkForeground
.AFGlobalLink

Comment: Let me check Florin Marcus. I ll get back to you. Thanks for your time

Comment: can you please help me with this......... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29674945/oracle-adf-adfc-10001-cannot-instantiate-class-com-wip-view-backing-index