# Oracle ADF: ADFC-10001: cannot instantiate class 'com.wip.view.backing.Index'

Tags: java, oracle, tomcat, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I have developed a web application using Oracle ADF Essantials. I am able to run this application on tomcat 6.x in my local system. I have the same tomcat 6.x environment on our server . There everything is same(tomcat environment). But when I am trying to run this application on server environment it is giving the following error.

```
HTTP Status 500 - oracle.adf.controller.ControllerException: ADFC-10001: cannot instantiate class 'com.wip.view.backing.Index'

type Exception report

message oracle.adf.controller.ControllerException: ADFC-10001: cannot instantiate class 'com.wip.view.backing.Index'

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: oracle.adf.controller.ControllerException: ADFC-10001: cannot instantiate class 'com.wip.view.backing.Index'
    javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:606)
    oracle.adf.model.servlet.ADFBindingFilter.doFilter(ADFBindingFilter.java:192)
    oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.webapp.rich.RegistrationFilter.doFilter(RegistrationFilter.java:105)
    org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl$FilterListChain.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:503)
    oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.activedata.AdsFilter.doFilter(AdsFilter.java:60)
    org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl$FilterListChain.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:503)
    org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl._doFilterImpl(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:327)
    org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:229)
    org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.webapp.TrinidadFilter.doFilter(TrinidadFilter.java:92)
root cause

javax.faces.FacesException: oracle.adf.controller.ControllerException: ADFC-10001: cannot instantiate class 'com.wip.view.backing.Index'
    oracle.adfinternal.controller.util.Utils.createAndLogFacesException(Utils.java:198)
    oracle.adfinternal.controller.beans.ManagedBeanFactory.newInstance(ManagedBeanFactory.java:189)
    oracle.adfinternal.controller.beans.ManagedBeanFactory.instantiateBean(ManagedBeanFactory.java:875)
    oracle.adfinternal.controller.state.ScopeMap.get(ScopeMap.java:82)
    javax.el.MapELResolver.getValue(MapELResolver.java:51)
    com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
    com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
    org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:123)
    org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:182)
    com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
```

and the following is the root cause..

```
root cause

oracle.adf.controller.ControllerException: ADFC-10001: cannot instantiate class 'com.wip.view.backing.Index'
    oracle.adfinternal.controller.util.Utils.createAndLogFacesException(Utils.java:190)
    oracle.adfinternal.controller.beans.ManagedBeanFactory.newInstance(ManagedBeanFactory.java:189)
    oracle.adfinternal.controller.beans.ManagedBeanFactory.instantiateBean(ManagedBeanFactory.java:875)
    oracle.adfinternal.controller.state.ScopeMap.get(ScopeMap.java:82)
    javax.el.MapELResolver.getValue(MapELResolver.java:51)
    com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
    com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
    org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:123)
    org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:182)
    com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
    com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.createComponentApplyAnnotations(ApplicationImpl.java:1941)
    com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.createComponent(ApplicationImpl.java:1144)
    com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.createComponent(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:518)
    com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:168)
    javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
    com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.core.ViewHandler.apply(ViewHandler.java:182)
```

I tried a lot fixing this isssue. But did not getting anyting. Finally I have made my local tomcat 6.x as .zip file and pasted this on server and run my app from this new environment but getting same error.

I observed the following difference between the urls in the browsers

In local browser
This is my URL: http://localhost:7777/EasyRUN/faces/index
after typing the url when I press enter am getting the same

```
http://localhost:7777/EasyRUN/faces/index
```

On server :
This is my URL: http://localhost:7777/EasyRUN/faces/index
after typing this url when I press enter am getting the below

```
http://localhost:7777/EasyRUN/faces/index;jsessionid=06186FB6D5EE4A1243224059F76C1A84?_afrLoop=105719567151&_afrWindowMode=2&Adf-Window-Id=w0
```

And I also tried with a test app that have only one page a.jsf. Same problem with this app. It is running on local environment and not running on server.

Please help.

Thanks in advance. Thank you very much. Please help.

Comment: When testing locally, are you deploying the EAR file, or you are using Jdeveloper?
Try to use the same deployment process on both.

Comment: for both local and on server am using war file. Help me for this please it is very urgent..... Thanks for you time

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for you help. I found the solution. The problem was I have jdk1.7 on my local system and on server I have 1.6. Thats why I faced that problem. Now on server also I have installed 1.7 my application is running successfully.

Thanks a lot for your help. Thank you very much.